# Disabling the draft option in a package

Tags: package-writing, draft, package-options

Within a package I'm making, I want ignore the default draft behavior and write my own. I have tried:

```
\DeclareOption{draft}{
MYCOMMANDS
...
\OptionNotUsed
}
\ProcessOptions
```

If `draft` is used, my commands are run, but all other features of the `draft` option (e.g. disabling images and hyperlinks) are still enabled.

I want to disable the `draft` option from the document class level from my package and prevent it from being passed to any packages. Is this possible to do from my package?

Comment: So you want to patch the code of other packages?

Comment: I would like to disable the draft option at the document class level and prevent it from being passed to any other packages.

Comment: You can't: if the `draft` option is specified with `\documentclass` it will be passed to all packages that know such option. Conversely, if it's specified only to your package, it will not be passed to other packages.

Comment: @David: This would only be possible (if it's possible at all) at class level. But you probably need to patch the option handling of LaTeX to make it work.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to specify the draft option at the class level and not for your package only? I think this would be the easiest option without any fiddling around with LaTeX internals.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the `draft` option is specified with `\documentclass` it will be passed to *all* packages that know such option. Conversely, if it's specified only along your package, it will not be passed to other packages.

```
\documentclass[<global options>]{<class>}
\usepackage[<local options>]{<package>}
```

The options in the `<global options>` list will be tried by the class and any package loaded in the preamble, but won't show errors or warnings if not known by a package.

The options in the `<local options>` list will be passed to `<package>` (which might pass them to other packages loaded after it, via `\PassOptionsToPackage`).

So with

```
\documentclass[draft,...]{article}
```

all packages will try to honor the `draft` option, and nothing can be done about this with code in some package.

However, if your package is loaded immediately after the class and you know how to modify the global options list, then it's possible to do what you wish. Here's the "secret" code:

```
\def\@clearglobaloption#1{%
  \def\@tempa{#1}%
  \let\@tempb\@gobble
  \@for\next:=\@classoptionslist\do
    {\ifx\next\@tempa
       \message{Cleared  option \next\space from global list}%
     \else
       \edef\@tempb{\@tempb,\next}%
     \fi}%
  \let\@classoptionslist\@tempb
  \ifx\@tempb\@gobble
    \let\@classoptionslist\@empty
  \fi}

\@clearglobaloption{draft}
```

I've made it generic: any option can be cleared in this way. Beware that some classes such as **beamer** do different things with the option list and so the trick might not work with them.

### Update

With `expl3` in the LaTeX kernel (which has been for a couple of years), we can simplify the business quite a lot.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:cpn { @clearglobaloption } #1
 {
  \clist_remove_all:cn { @classoptionslist } { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Don't many packages also have a `final` package option that overrides a `draft` class option for the purposes of that specific package?

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the "secret" code, if the first kept option starts with twice the same letter the `\ifx` matches and we get text before `\begin{document}` ...

Comment: @VincentBeffara `\ifx` the two macros `\next` and `\@tempa`, returning true if they have the same replacement text

Comment: No I mean the second `\ifx` to test for the empty case. If `\@tempb` ends up being `aa,whatever` then it tests the first `a` against the second one

Comment: @VincentBeffara oh, I see. Needs a fix

Comment: Probably `\clist_remove_all:Nn` would make more sense these days anyway

Comment: @VincentBeffara Sure! A good occasion for fixing the mistake and for showing a much simpler approach.