# Stop my class passing options on to article class

Tags: draft, class-options

I have a class file which declares some options.  One of them is called `draft`.  This places a watermark on all pages that says `DRAFT`.

```
\DeclareOption{draft}{  
    \RequirePackage{draftwatermark}
    \SetWatermarkText{\textbf{DRAFT}}
}
```

I include the following line because I thought that it stops any declared options getting passed along when I call `\LoadClass`

```
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
```

Followed by

```
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
```

However, whenever I pass the class my `draft` argument, it is getting passed to `article`, and getting rid of all my figures.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Any option in the `\documentclass` line is passed to *all* packages loaded afterwards, including `graphicx`. You can avoid it by saying `\usepackage[final]{graphicx}`

Comment: You might find this question useful on removing options: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33245/86

Answer (score 6):

Passing `draft` to article does not affect graphic inclusion. But global options are seen by all packages so a `[draft]` on `\documentclass` stops figure inclusion unless you use `final` on `\usepackage[final]{graphicx}` or on the individual calls `\includegraphics[draft=false]{...}` or use `\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}` to reset the graphics draft flag.

Comment: Your statement that "global options are seen by all packages" and egreg's "any option in the `\documentclass` line is passed to all packages" leave me confused, since the definition of `\ProcessOptions` says `\@ifstar\@xprocess@ptions\@process@ptions` and `\@process@ptions` doesn't copy class options.

Comment: They are not passed down by the same mechanism but processoptions, if it is not handling a .cls file process the saved class options: `\def\@process@ptions{%
  \@for\CurrentOption:=\@declaredoptions\do{%
    \ifx\CurrentOption\@empty\else
      \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\CurrentOption,}{%
         ,\ifx\@currext\@clsextension\else\@classoptionslist,\fi
         \@curroptions,}%
      \ifin@
        \@use@ption
        \expandafter\let\csname ds@\CurrentOption\endcsname\@empty
      \fi
    \fi}%
  \@process@pti@ns}`

Comment: `\ifx\@currext\@clsextension\else\@classoptionslist` being the bit to stare at

Comment: OK, seen it. Airheaded here.