# How to hide a global option from babel

Tags: babel, options

I am using a non-public class that has an option named `english` for setting up certain texts.  I wish to use `babel` for hyphenation and to specify the language (variant) as british.  However,

```
\usepackage[main=british]{babel}
```

produces the warning

```
 Package Babel Warning: The package option `english' should not be used
 (Babel)                with a more specific one (like `british') on input line 4.
```

I get the same warning if I try `\PassOptionsToPackage{main=british}{babel}` before loading the documentclass.

Here is a minimal working example using the `article` class instead:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage[main=british]{babel}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

What is the correct way to load `babel` with `british` when the document class uses `english` to set other document features that I need.

Comment: The `english` option is supposed to be used only by your class, or is it only `babel` which is not supposed to see `english`?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33245/disabling-the-draft-option-in-a-package

Comment: Apparently it works as expected, and `\today` and hyphenation are correct. This warning was due to an old and severe bug which messed up the date and hyphenation in some cases, but not all. I have to investigate the exact issue (to be honest, I don't remember it) to improve the message.

Comment: Seems like a Brexit problem to me. ;-)

Comment: @Marijn Thank that essentially works and this can be closed as a duplicate.  However I have noted below how I used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marijn pointed to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33389/15925 which will work, when the code is put in the main document and wrapped in `\makeatletter...\makeatother`.  But
Phelye Oleinik notes that there is a cleaner answer using LaTeX internals

```
\documentclass[english]{unusualcls}

\makeatletter
\@expandtwoargs\@removeelement{english}\@classoptionslist\@classoptionslist
\makeatother

\usepackage[main=british]{babel}

\begin{document}

Some \unusualtext.

\end{document}
```

where `unusual.cls` is

```
\ProvidesClass{unusualcls}[2010/12/15 v0.0001]

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

\def\unusualtext{Patagonian}
\DeclareOptionX{english}{\gdef\unusualtext{English}}

\ProcessOptionsX*

\LoadClass{article}
```

In either case you will get

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [english].
```

if the option is not used, e.g. by the class file, before the clearing code.

Comment: LaTeX already has `\@removeelement` to do that: `\@expandtwoargs\@removeelement{english}\@classoptionslist\@classoptionslist`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Much simpler.  Sounds like you should make that an answer to the duplicate question.